# Error en mi arreglo en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un programa para generar números pseudoaleatorios por medio del método congruencial mixto, pero me tira un error en una de las lineas de código.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double c, a, m, sem, res = 0, lim = 0, conta = 0, i = 0;
        int j = 0, cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese constante aditiva");
        c = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Constante Multiplicativa");
        a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese modulo");
        m = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese semilla");
        sem = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] vector = new double[100];
        double[] v = new double[4];
        double[] ve = new double[5];

        int[] resultado = new int[100];
        //suma = num1 + num2;
        while (res != 1)
        {
            lim = sem;
            res = ((sem * a) + c) % m;
            sem = res;

            //conta++;
            //Console.WriteLine("" + res / m);
           vector[j] = res / m;
          j++;

        }

        //Console.WriteLine("Periodo " + conta);
        for (int k = 0; k < vector.Length; k++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("" + vector[k]);
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < vector.Length; l++)
        {
            for (int w = 1; w < vector.Length - 1; w++)
            {
                if (vector[l] < vector[w])
                {
                    resultado[l] = 0;


                }
                else if (vector[l] > vector[w])
                {
                    resultado[l] = 1;

                }
            }

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < resultado.Length; k++)
        {
            //if(resultado[k]=resultado[k+1])
            if (resultado[k] == 1)
                if (resultado[k] == 1)
                    if (resultado[k] == 1)
                        if (resultado[k] == 1)
                            if (resultado[k] == 1)
                            {

                                cont1 = 5;
                            }
                            else cont1 = 4;
                        else cont1 = 3;
                    else cont1 = 2;
                else cont1 = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Vector Resultado" + "[" + resultado[k] + "]" + cont1);

         }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    }
}
```

El error me da en la siguiente linea de codigo

```
   vector[j] = res / m;
          j++;
```

Me da el siguente error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor

Answer (score 2):

Lo que te ocurre es que res no llega a valer nunca 1, o que tu vector es muy chico para soportar los valores que necesita tu programa.
Un error de ese tipo te lo desata en cuanto sucede res[100] = algo, porque está fuera de los límites de tu vector

Answer (score 0):

Como `res` **nunca cambia su valor** este bucle se ejecuta de manera infinita, por lo que `j` llega rápidamente a ser `>=100` lo que implica que estas tratando de acceder a la posición `101` de un arreglo de solo `100` posiciones.

```
while (res != 1)
{
    lim = sem;
    res = ((sem * a) + c) % m;
    sem = res;

    //EN ESTE PUNTO FALLA CUANDO j == 100
   vector[j] = res / m;
  j++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un ciclo `while` y no estas condicionándolo con tu variable iteradora que indica el índice de tu arreglo, al sobrepasar el máximo índice de tu arreglo te genera la excepción:

```
while (j < vector.Length)
{
    lim = sem;
    res = ((sem * a) + c) % m;
    sem = res;

    //conta++;
    //Console.WriteLine("" + res / m);
    vector[j] = res / m;
    j++;
}
```